# jQuery - Loading external webpages into a div from dynamic RSS feed links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rss, loading

My webpage contains some RSS feeds from some random sites.

There are links within these feeds which take you to these sites. Is there anyway to load these webpages into a div on my page?

The problem Im having is that these RSS links are created dynamically when I create my RSS feeds.

Dose anyone have any suggestions?

```
function showLTab(key)
{
    var myObject = science[key];
    var stage = $("#leftFeed").children('#tabContent');

    //forming the query
    //LIMT controls amount of tabs displayed in each feed
    var query = "select * from feed where url='"+myObject.feed+"' LIMIT 5";


    //changing URL to YQL
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="+encodeURIComponent(query)+"&format=json&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(url,function(data){

        //removes any previous feeds
        stage.empty();

        //item exists in RSS
        $.each(data.query.results.item || data.query.results.entry,function(){
                stage.append(myObject['function'](this));
        })
    });

    $("#leftFeed").children('#activeTab').text(key);
}


function showLeftDropDown()
{
    var activeTab = $("#leftFeed").children('#activeTab');
    //creating drop down div
    var dropDown = $('<div>').addClass('dropDownList').css({'top': 10, 'width': activeTab.width()}).hide().appendTo('#leftFeed');

    $.each(science,function(i){
        // populates dropdown div
        if(i==activeTab.text()) return true;
            $('<div>').text(i).appendTo(dropDown);
    })
    dropDown.slideDown('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL of the page that interests you (that is to say, this question is about the display of the page and not the retrieval of the links) and simply want to spit out the result into a container such as a `div`, you can do this:

```
$("#myDiv").load("page url");
```

This passes an Ajax request to the given url and loads the content into the selected element. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more info.

Another option is using `iframes`. You can create an `iframe` and then set the `src` property to the url that you are interested in using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "page url";
```

---

Okay, so if you don't know the URL but have the feed that you can parse, try a regex. Given that links look like this:

```
<link>http://www.someexamplerssdomain.com/main.html</link>
```

You can use this code to parse them all out into an array:

```
var regex = /<link>(.*?)<\/link>/gi;
var matches = new Array();

var match = regex.exec(rssInput);
while (match != null) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(rssInput);
}
```

You can then use either of the two methods I first suggested to retrieve their content.

Comment: The problem is that I dont know the url. The url is generated dynamically by the RSS feed....

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery 
https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

it will help u

Comment: I cant use any plugins. This is a college assignment.
Thanks though